# instancia corriendo con datos distribuidos en varios discos

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Tengo un disco duro que se me esta llenando y voy a añadir otro. En ese disco duro tengo una BBDD MySQL y quiero saber si al colocar otro HD puedo, con esa misma instancia de MySQL, almacenar tablas en el disco nuevo, o si tengo que tener 2 instancias de MySQL corriendo en el mismo PC para poder hacerlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La respuesta de Marc es correcta. Sin embargo, yo optaría por mover todo el subdirectorio de tablas a tu disco nuevo (el siguiente ejemplo funcionaría en linux)

Dado que hayas montado el nuevo disco en `/var/newdisk`, tendrías que

1. crear un subdirectorio para la data de mysql (pq imagino que el disco nuevo alojará otras cosas)
2. detener el servicio mysql
3. copiar las tablas a la nueva ubicación

eso sería:

```
mkdir /var/newdisk/mysql_new
sudo service mysql stop
rsync -avzr /var/lib/mysql/ /var/newdisk/mysql_new/
```

luego:

4. modificar el archivo de configuración de mysql (usualmente `mysqld.cnf`) y por si acaso, copiándolo a un `mysqld.cnf.bak` por si algo sale mal.
5. cambiar el parámetro `datadir` en ese archivo

poniendo o reemplazando el parámetro existente:

```
datadir=/var/newdisk/mysql_new/
```

6. reiniciar el servicio mysql

(con sudo)

```
sudo service mysql start
```

Tu directorio original sigue intacto así que puedes echar pie atrás restableciendo la configuración original.

Answer (score 1):

Buenas ZiPoTaTo,

Si puedes, para realizar esta opción debes usar la opción que tiene `MYSQL` (con `InnoDB`) para poder crear y almacenar las tablas en otra unidad que no sea el directorio por defecto ([`file_per_table`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/glossary.html#glos_file_per_table)).

Primero deberías poner la variable en estado `ON` si no lo está:

```
//Miramos el estado de la variable
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_file_per_table';

//Si no está en ON (1) la ponemos en ON
SET GLOBAL innodb_file_per_table=1;
```

Un ejemplo de cómo crear una tabla en una unidad diferente a la asignada por defecto es:

```
CREATE TABLE nombreTabla (col1 INT PRIMARY KEY) DATA DIRECTORY = '/path';
```

De ésta manera estás indicando que la tabla que estas creando la vas a almacenar en el path proporcionado.